# ReportViewer with ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have developed SSRS report and deployed on server. The report has dropdown, based on dropdown selection report data varies since this dropdown value is passed as Parameter to report. The report works just fine when accessed directly.

Now I have integrated this report into my ASP.net MVC 3 application using ReportViewer. 
When report is accessed thru web application page appears to be loading correctly but when I click on View Report it shows message "Loading" for a while and then displays nothing.
I'm clueless on this and not understanding this behavior at all.

---

**UPDATE**

I found solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547454/287100

Comment: possible that your working process is not within your SSRS group permissions you have on the report server,   maybe ????

Comment: @ElYusubov I appreciate your help, thanks. But I have already integrated reports in my site and the links you have given are not helpful for solving my issue.

Comment: @Pramodtech, this is strange that it did not work for you.what asp.net framework are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Viewing SSRS Reports in an ASP.net MVC Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137835/viewing-ssrs-reports-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site)

Answer (score 6):

This is a particular question where you need to **combine ASP.NET web-forms with MVC**, which is perfectly fine. Because, **ReportViewer control won't work** if you place it in an **MVC view**, as it **requires ViewState**.

How to **make SSRS work**? well follow this article - [Incorporating ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=1009061&printmode=true)

Another post that shows **benefits of combining web-forms with mvc** - [Viewing SSRS Reports in an ASP.net MVC Site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4137835/1437962)